# Lambda Function for 2 Different Launch Templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

So I have two different launch templates I am spinning up into 2 AZs. The code runs successfully, but only the first launch template "lt" runs successfully. Why is that?

```
import boto3

# I have called the EC2 resource
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

# I have defined my launch template
lt = {
    
    'LaunchTemplateName': 'My_Launch_Template',
    'Version': '1'
}

lt_a = {
    
    'LaunchTemplateName': 'My_Launch_Template_2',
    'Version': '1'
}

# I have defined a function to execute 
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    instances = ec2.create_instances(
        LaunchTemplate=lt,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    instances = ec2.create_instances(
        LaunchTemplate=lt_a,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1
    )
```

Comment: Is this code that you are providing to an AWS Lambda function? Why are there two `lambda_handler()` methods? The second one would simply overwrite the first one. What are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: Interesting, John. 
I want to launch two similar launch templates in different subnets or AZs, I created one for AZ1 and the other for AZ2.

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name in the same Python script. That's not valid Python code. You need to split these into two separate files, or rename one of the `lambda_handler` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't valid Python code. I suggest you review the basics of the language before you start implementing the function on AWS lambda. Get all of your code working on your local machine and once you're happy, move it to AWS.

Anyway, I would rewrite your code to have a helper function. This way you maximize code reuse (and you make your life easier):

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def create_instance(launch_template_name, launch_template_id):
    lt = {
        'LaunchTemplateName': launch_template_name,
        'Version': launch_template_id
    }
    return ec2.create_instanceS(
        LaunchTemplate=lt,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    first_instance = create_instance('My_Launch_Template', '1')
    second_instance = create_instance('My_Launch_Template_2', '1')
    ...
```

Comment: Omg, my python is so scruffy! I have been spending so much time wrapping my head around SysOps. Thanks for always coming through, Paolo. I'm going to study again and work towards mastering python for sure, I will.

Comment: How do I add a deployed instance into an auto-scaling group?

Comment: @charlesklaus please open a new question for that